# How can I print the full stack trace with GlassFish?

Tags: logging, glassfish, glassfish-3

I have a [GlassFish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GlassFish) web application which throws errors (listed below) to the webbrowser. But my problem is that I can't see the **full** stack trace. I think I have to know what the real problem is. How can I change the length of the stack trace?

```
javax.ejb.EJBException
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.processSystemException(BaseContainer.java:5119)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:5017)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4805)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2004)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1955)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:198)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:84)
 at $Proxy158.findRange(Unknown Source)
 at ejb.__EJB31_Generated__NewEntityFacade__Intf____Bean__.findRange(Unknown Source)
 at jsf.NewEntityController$1.createPageDataModel(NewEntityController.java:56)
 at jsf.NewEntityController.getItems(NewEntityController.java:155)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:302)
 at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:175)
 at com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:72)
 at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:116)
 at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:163)
 at com.sun.el.parser.AstEqual.getValue(AstEqual.java:54)
 at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:219)
 at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:102)
 at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:190)
 at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.isRendered(UIComponentBase.java:416)
 at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1607)
 at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
 at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:848)
 at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1613)
 at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1616)
 at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1616)
 at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:380)
 at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:126)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:127)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
 at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:313)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
 at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
 at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:325)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:226)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
 at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
 at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
 at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
 at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
 at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
 at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
 at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
 at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
 at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
 at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
 at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
 at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
 at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The type [null] is not the expected [EntityType] for the key class [class Persistence.NewEntity].
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.entity(MetamodelImpl.java:152)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.querydef.AbstractQueryImpl.from(AbstractQueryImpl.java:97)
 at ejb.AbstractFacade.findRange(AbstractFacade.java:48)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1056)
 at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1128)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5292)
 at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:615)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:797)
 at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:567)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:157)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:139)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor94.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:858)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:797)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:367)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5264)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5252)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:190)
 ... 55 more
```

Comment: This is a good question! And there must be a better way than surrounding culprit code with a try/catch (you're not going to do that in production)... Will need to dig this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167888/howto-increase-lines-of-java-stack-trace-dump) among other places. Wrap suspected function calls in a try-catch block and print the stack trace only if you're in debug mode (for security reasons). You should be able to get what you need from there.

Comment: i don't get how that could help me. They talk about System.print and i have a JSF application.

Comment: It can help you because `EJBException` has a printStackTrace method just like any other `Throwable`. See here: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/ejb/EJBException.html#printStackTrace()

Comment: If you don't know how to print text to the web browser, http://www.ensode.net/java_servlet_stacktrace_browser.html

Comment: so i have to ovveride the printStackTrace Method?

Comment: No, you can just call `printStackTrace()` when you catch an `EJBException`. To print the full stack trace, use the original link in my answer. And to send it to the web browser use the `ensode.net` link I posted above. But as Pascal says, there's definitely a better way. I just don't know it.