# show full stack trace when an Exception occurs

Tags: java, exception, tomcat, logging, stack-trace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [howto increase lines of java stack trace dump?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167888/howto-increase-lines-of-java-stack-trace-dump)

I'm writing a Java Application for tomcat. whenever an Exception is being thrown I get the name of the Exception and the stack trace and in the end if it's a long trace I get
`... X more`.

how can I configure tomcat to show a full stack trace ?

thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not Tomcat's fault, it's the way the `Throwable.printStackTraceAsCause(PrintStream s, StackTraceElement[] causedTrace)` method implements the printing of stacktraces.

```
 /**
     * Print our stack trace as a cause for the specified stack trace.
     */
    private void printStackTraceAsCause(PrintStream s,
                                        StackTraceElement[] causedTrace)
    {
        // assert Thread.holdsLock(s);

        // Compute number of frames in common between this and caused
        StackTraceElement[] trace = getOurStackTrace();
        int m = trace.length-1, n = causedTrace.length-1;
        while (m >= 0 && n >=0 && trace[m].equals(causedTrace[n])) {
            m--; n--;
        }
        int framesInCommon = trace.length - 1 - m;

        s.println("Caused by: " + this);
        for (int i=0; i <= m; i++)
            s.println("\tat " + trace[i]);
        if (framesInCommon != 0)
            s.println("\t... " + framesInCommon + " more");

        // Recurse if we have a cause
        Throwable ourCause = getCause();
        if (ourCause != null)
            ourCause.printStackTraceAsCause(s, trace);
    }
```

If you want, you can print your stacktraces yourself in a log file (or `response.getOutputStream()`) by getting first displaying the message of the caught element and then displaying the array element of `StackTraceElement` (which can be found by calling `Throwable.getStackTrace()` method).