# Runtime Exception - How Do Obtain All Log Entries From Logcat?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [howto increase lines of java stack trace dump?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167888/howto-increase-lines-of-java-stack-trace-dump)

I'm having some problems with my app, a runtime exception is being thrown when the device is re-orientated (oddly only when going from Landscape to Portrait and not vice versa!). I've looked at the logcat output with this command:

> adb logcat AndroidRuntime:E *:S

and obtained the following (the XX.XXXX.XXX etc is my package name obliterated):

```
> E/AndroidRuntime(  559): FATAL EXCEPTION: main E/AndroidRuntime( 
> 559): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity
> {xx.xx.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxx/xx.xx.xxxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxx}:
> java.lang.NullPointerException E/AndroidRuntime(  559):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3655)
> E/AndroidRuntime(  559):  at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3673)
> E/AndroidRuntime(  559):  at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3789)
> E/AndroidRuntime(  559):  at
> android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:125)
> E/AndroidRuntime(  559):  at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2037)
> E/AndroidRuntime(  559):  at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) E/AndroidRuntime( 
> 559):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) E/AndroidRuntime( 
> 559):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
> E/AndroidRuntime(  559):  at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) E/AndroidRuntime(
> 559):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
> E/AndroidRuntime(  559):  at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
> E/AndroidRuntime(  559):  at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
> E/AndroidRuntime(  559):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
> Method) E/AndroidRuntime(  559): Caused by:
> java.lang.NullPointerException E/AndroidRuntime(  559):   at
> xx.xx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxx.onDestroy(XXXXXXXXXXX.java:565)
> E/AndroidRuntime(  559):  at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3642)
> E/AndroidRuntime(  559):  ... 12 more
```

The problem I have is in the very last line of the logcat output:

```
> E/AndroidRuntime( 559): ... 12 more
```

How do I get access to the '12 more'? I assume this will point to the line of my code that is causing the problem.

Thanks

Comment: I found an answer [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167888/howto-increase-lines-of-java-stack-trace-dump