# Java exception stack being suppressed - how to print out entire stack?

Tags: java, ant

n: I am getting the following Java exception stack.  As you can see towards the bottom that the stack is being suppressed (notice the "... 5 more" indicator from Java below).

The java program is being launched as an Ant task.  Does anyone know how to get either Java or Ant to print out the entire error stack?

```
 [java] javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory
 [java]       at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:615)
 [java]       at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnection(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:121)
 [java]       at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnection(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:116)
 [java]       at org.hornetq.jms.example.QueueExample.runExample(QueueExample.java:56)
 [java]       at org.hornetq.common.example.HornetQExample.run(HornetQExample.java:76)
 [java]       at org.hornetq.jms.example.QueueExample.main(QueueExample.java:35)
 [java] Caused by: HornetQException[errorCode=2 message=Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]
 [java]       at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:619)
 [java]       at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:611)
 [java]       ... 5 more
 [java]
 [java] #####################
 [java] ###    FAILURE!   ###
 [java] #####################
 [java] Java Result: 1
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167888/howto-increase-lines-of-java-stack-trace-dump

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to see the entire stack. the ...5 indicates that the following 5 [StackTraceElement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html)s are the last 5 elements from wrapper Exception(in your case: javax.jms.JMSException). For more information visit the [printStacktrace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace%28%29) method on Javadoc, it includes a pretty detailed example of what you see in your stacktrace