# mvn -e Complete Stack Trace?

Tags: maven

I'm kinda new to maven and I'm assuming this is a maven thing and not something to do with my shell, but when I run with the -e switch to try and identify an error, I get something incomplete like this:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Deployment failed and was rolled back.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Deployment failed and was rolled back.
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:719)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.jboss.as.plugin.common.DeploymentExecutionException: Deployment failed and was rolled back.
at org.jboss.as.plugin.deployment.standalone.StandaloneDeployment.execute(StandaloneDeployment.java:140)
at org.jboss.as.plugin.deployment.AbstractDeployment.executeDeployment(AbstractDeployment.java:119)
at org.jboss.as.plugin.deployment.AbstractDeployment.doExecute(AbstractDeployment.java:141)
at org.jboss.as.plugin.deployment.AbstractAppDeployment.doExecute(AbstractAppDeployment.java:70)
at org.jboss.as.plugin.deployment.AbstractDeployment.execute(AbstractDeployment.java:111)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
... 17 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I see the "... 17 more" things? I believe it will help me find out exactly which maven task is failing? Thanks for any help or links to documentation!

P.S. If you are curious and feel the urge to help me figure out the actual problem, I am simply running "mvn clean package jboss-as:deploy" to deploy, and I could provide more info in another question specific to the problem if I don't figure it out myself.

Comment: The 'more things' should already be present elsewhere in the stacktrace - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167888/howto-increase-lines-of-java-stack-trace-dump, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @PaulGrime That looks to be the case, thank you for the link!

Comment: Can you try using both `-e -X` Maven switches, to get the full logs.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't strictly an answer, but it might help your investigation.

The source code for [StandaloneDeployment (line 140)](https://github.com/jbossas/jboss-as-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/plugin/deployment/standalone/StandaloneDeployment.java#L140) (warning, this may not be the version you are using) shows the place where the [`DeploymentExecutionException`](https://github.com/jbossas/jboss-as-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/plugin/common/DeploymentExecutionException.java) is thrown:

```
case ROLLED_BACK:
    throw new DeploymentExecutionException("Deployment failed and was rolled back.", actionResult.getDeploymentException());
```

and a root exception (`actionResult.getDeploymentException()`) is passed to this `DeploymentExecutionException`.

I would have thought you would get to see this root exception in the Maven stack trace, but it seems not in your case.

You could always try [debugging the plugin itself](http://netsuke.wordpress.com/2008/03/09/see-how-maven-works-inside-remote-debugging-plugins/), and putting a breakpoint on the line shown above.

Comment: Again, thanks. This is good information, even though I'm not using Eclipse. If I still can't figure it out after too long, I'll post more detailed server info in another question.

Comment: The debugging itself is not reliant on Eclipse. If you have another IDE, it will have similar functionality to attach itself to a debugging Java process.