# How to watch a full output error message in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jakarta-mail

I built my code successfully and then I had a problem.

This is my code:

```
package EmailSending;
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.activation.*;

public class launcher {
    public static void main(String[] args){

      final String username = "my-email@yandex.ru";
      final String password = "my-password";

      String to = "to-email@mail.ru";

      String from = "from-email@yandex.ru";

      String host = "localhost";

      Properties properties = System.getProperties();
      properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
      properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
      properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);

      Session session = Session.getInstance(properties);

      try{

         MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

         message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

         message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                                  new InternetAddress(to));

         message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");

         message.setText("This is actual message");

         Transport.send(message);
         System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
      }catch (MessagingException mex) {
         mex.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

There is an error at this line: 
`Session session = Session.getInstance(properties);`
This is an output message:

```
run:
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/mail/util/MailLogger
    at javax.mail.Session.initLogger(Session.java:227)
    at javax.mail.Session.<init>(Session.java:212)
    at javax.mail.Session.getInstance(Session.java:265)
    at EmailSending.launcher.main(launcher.java:34)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.mail.util.MailLogger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 4 more
Java Result: 1
```

How can I watch a full output error message in NetBeans? How to expand "...4 more"?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please add the part of your code which throws the exception?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java

Comment: Thank you, but my question is about how I can watch the whole error message.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I increase the number of displayed lines of a Java stack trace dump?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167888/how-do-i-increase-the-number-of-displayed-lines-of-a-java-stack-trace-dump)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you haven't figured it out, the cause of that exception is that you haven't added the right JavaMail library to your project.  See [this JavaMail FAQ entry](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#libnetbeans).

If you're using Maven, you might want to refer to the Maven coordinates for JavaMail listed [here](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Download_JavaMail_1.5.1_Release).  You want [com.sun.mail:javax.mail](https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/com/sun/mail/javax.mail/1.5.1/javax.mail-1.5.1.jar).