# how to let Apache Pig record entire exception stack trace

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

I'm debugging a UDF used for Apache Pig, and there's an exception occurred. Pig automatically recorded the stack trace into some log files looks like :

> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>
> at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop20.PigJobControl.mainLoopAction(PigJobControl.java:157)
>
> ... 3 more

however, I want to view all of that stack trace instead of '...3 more', how can I do this?

Thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I increase the number of displayed lines of a Java stack trace dump?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167888/how-do-i-increase-the-number-of-displayed-lines-of-a-java-stack-trace-dump)

Comment: Yeah, though there's still something different, I think they are similar. How to mark it `duplicate`?