# Exception "... 18 more" what does it means in stacktrace Java?

Tags: java

In Java stacktrace let say I have an `exception`

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.test.MainClass(MyClass.java:92)
    at com.test.MainClass(MyThread.java:328)
    ... 22 more
```

I want to know what does this `... 22 more` means and why it is not showing full stack trace and is it possible to enable full stack trace.

Comment: Because the main cause of error is at MyClass.java at line number 92

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167888/how-do-i-increase-the-number-of-displayed-lines-of-a-java-stack-trace-dump

Comment: @RicardoBarroca thanks for searching it, i searched before posting this question but could not found that one. (Y)